# How to display all images in different page using Javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating an app using jQuery and Javascript that shows the image in a page when given the URL of the page.

I have this currently:

```js
$.get('https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/smart-phone-computer-ram-icon-260nw-605660063.jpg', null, function(text){
    document.write(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I put the URL which is `https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/smart-phone-computer-ram-icon-260nw-605660063.jpg`

But when I run this, i get some random text instead of the image...

Is there anyway to get the image?

Answer (score 0):

To let the user type something you need an `input` element. To display an image you need to use an `img` element. `img` elements have a `src` attribute in which you provide the URL of the image you want to display.

To achieve what you described call a function when the user enters something into the input. This function takes the value from the input field and sets it as the `src` attribute of the `img`.

```js
const showImage = () => {
  const url = document.getElementById('url').value;
  document.getElementById('image').src = url;
}
```

```html
<input id="url" oninput="showImage();" />
<br />
<img id="image" />
```